# Comment comprendre « mon cœur … n’a jamais voulu détacher des paroles versées, et le sang » ?

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques, paroles-de-chanson, figure-de-style

Cette question porte sur la chanson *les vieux temps* des *Ogres de Barback.*
Je me débats avec deux mots donc je n’aperçois pas comment ils se rapportent à la phrase à laquelle ils appartiennent. Il s’agit de *détacher* et de *versées*.

> Mon cœur empli de ces baisers, du vieux temps et des amants, 
>       N'a jamais voulu **détacher** les paroles **versées** et le sang.

Je connais les deux mots un peu. Malheureusement, il y a tant de façons de les utiliser que j’ai du mal à comprendre leurs fonctions ici. Qu’est-ce qui vous vient à l’esprit quand vous lisez l’extrait donné ?

*Mes propres pensées*

Peut-être le parolier fait semblant que les paroles sont des travailleurs de son cœur, pour ainsi dire. Alors, les paroles versées sont celles qui ont beaucoup éprouvé et qui savent comment agir. Sachant que *détacher* est apparenté à *démettre*, en parlant de travailleurs, je suis enclin à penser que ce morceau fait pendant à un licenciement de ces paroles et du sang.

J’ai aussi pensé que le cœur a versé, (c’est-à-dire répandu) des paroles sur un tapis ou quelque chose de semblable, comme si elles étaient une boisson. En ce cas, je dirais que le cœur n’enlève pas les taches qui sont ainsi apparues sur le tapis parce qu’il n’a pas de remords concernant ce qu’il avait dit.

La dernière chose dont je me suis douté, c’est que *verser* ait un lien avec *sang* : je me souviens d’avoir lu que *verser le sang* veut dire *porter atteinte à quelqu’un par dépit.* Je ne saurais pas dire, néanmoins, ce que les mots en gras ajoutent à la phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice song, thanks for sharing!

Je crois, comme [cl-r dit dans sa réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/12328/79), que « détacher » ici veut dire « séparer » et que « le sang » ici symbolise « la vie ».

Pour « les paroles versées », je crois que c’est une référence directe à la première phrase du vers dont les deux phrases citées viennent :

> J'ai bu tant de tes paroles, t'écoutant des heures, comme ça.

Je vois « paroles versées » en correspondance avec « paroles bues », donc pour moi, « verser » ici veut dire « servir » ou même « partager », comme du vin, quoi.

Tout ca pour arriver plus au moins au même résultat que cl-r en disant que:

« Le cœur du poète, plein d’amour et des souvenirs, n’a jamais voulu séparer les paroles versées/partagées avec son aimée et la vie avec elle.  Autrement dit, peut-être, qu’il ne voulait jamais que leurs paroles partagées ni leur vie partagée prennent fin. »

Answer (score 2):

L'origine latine  de l'adjectif *versé* : versatus, de versari "Vivre habituellement dans, s'occuper de".
 Littérature : *Versé dans* : qui est expérimenté et savant (en une matière), qui a une longue expérience.

Les *paroles versées*, semblent se rattacher ainsi aux paroles qu'un "... cœur empli de ces baisers, du vieux temps et des amants," peut avoir habilement prononcé au cours de ses expériences amoureuses.

Mais ce même cœur, savant des mille choses de l'amour, ne peut séparer cet amour ardent et poétiquement chanté, du sang, symbole de la vie, du battement cardiaque soumis aux désirs d’Éros.